# Detect if user must reset password In Active Directory 

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to detect if a user must reset his password in Active Directory. I'm using a console app written in C#.

I have virtual dedicated server on GoDaddy I am trying to run

```
string strUserName = userName;
user = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://0.0.0.0", "GodadyLogiUserInfo", "GodadyLogiUserPass", AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(user);

searcher.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + <USERWHICHNEEDTOTEST>+ ")";
searcher.CacheResults = false;

// Find user
SearchResult result = searcher.FindOne();
user = result.GetDirectoryEntry();
```

It throws error

> The server is not operational.

I tried many ways on SOF and many sites but could not find.

Answer (score 1):

`LDAP://0.0.0.0` is a valid address for the server to listen at. It isn't a valid address for a client to try to connect to. You have to supply a proper hostname or IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to connect AD like this :

```
/* Connexion to Active Directory
 */
string sFromWhere = "LDAP://ServerDnsName:389/dc=dom,dc=..";
DirectoryEntry deBase = new DirectoryEntry(sFromWhere, "ADUser", "ADPwd");
```